# How do I, if it can be done that is, approve some but not all edits to a question I have posted made by a fellow user/

Tags: support

Essentially the question title says it all.

On a couple of occasions recently fellow users have edited questions that I have posted.  In the main I have no issue with the edits and they generally reflect what I ought to have written were I not such an awful non-touch typist.  However every now and then people add edits which clearly demonstrate a lack of understanding both of grammar and correct english usage and on occasions those edits would alter the meaning of the question.  How can one selectively accept some but not all edits, or is it a case of select or reject all?

Comment: That was the edit that prompted the question,  but it left me wondering if it was in fact possible to selectively accept an edit, an obviously comment on those bits one agrees with and more importantly why one disagrees with others.

Comment: A minor suggestion, please don't include "thanks" in your questions. [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950)

Answer (score 3):

Are you talking about [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9105756)? That edit should indeed be rejected... A lot of that user's edits break previously fine grammar and worse.

As you're the owner of the post, you can accept or reject one suggested edit entirely. It's not possible to partially accept an edit.

I don't know if you have a "Reject and Edit" button. If you do, use it. If not, reject and fix the parts you wanted to fix.

Comment: Thank you that makes complete sense.